# Is it possible to parameterize table and column names in SQLite queries?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Im trying to perform a parameterized query in SQLite from C#, and the method im using is along the lines of creating a static command with

```
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(
        "SELECT [ID]" +
            ",[email]" +
            ",[serializedata]" +
            ",[restrictions]" +
        " FROM " + UserTable +
        " WHERE @search = @searchparam", SQLConnection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@searchparam"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@search"));
```

and calling it like this:

```
        Command.Parameters["@searchparam"].Value = searchdata;
        Command.Parameters["@search"].Value = search;
        SQLiteDataAdapter slda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(UserSelectUsernameCommand);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        slda.Fill(ds);
        User[] array = new User[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            array[index] = new User(this, row);
            index++;
        }
        return array;
```

but im getting an error along the line of " '@search' is not a correct column name " or something like that. if i use a constant column name, and only use the data for parameters it works, but i dont want to create 10 different commands for when i need to search by different column names.

What is the issue here?

Comment: If you are avoiding creating 10 different commands because of the inefficiency of tying each one to a SqliteConnection and building up their parameters and CommandText over and over, I'm just making sure that readers know that there is an alternative.  SqliteCommand has a parameterless constructor of just 
new SqliteCommand(); and its Connection property is assignable at run time.  So you can create and initialize many commands just once and then assign their Connection property to a SqliteConnection object that is repeatedly created and disposed at run time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally things like column names (or table names) can **not** be parameterised - and the fact that there are different indices means that it will *have* to be a different plan internally. So you will have to use concatenation - **but** be careful to white-list the known column names to prevent sql injection:

```
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"
    SELECT [ID],[email],[serializedata],[restrictions]
    FROM " + whiteListedUserTable + @"
    WHERE [" + whiteListedColumnName + @"] = @searchparam", SQLConnection);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@searchparam"));
    ...
    Command.Parameters["@searchparam"].Value = searchdata;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a query parameter in that fashion -- to indicate a column name.  You can only use it to supply values.

Consider something like this instead:

```
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(
    "SELECT [ID]" +
        ",[email]" +
        ",[serializedata]" +
        ",[restrictions]" +
    " FROM " + UserTable +
    " WHERE [" + search + "] = @searchparam", SQLConnection);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@searchparam"));
```

If you control all of the input to this function and none if it can be supplied by someone other than you, this should be safe.  But if `search` comes from an untrusted third party, be sure to make the appropriate security checks on the value.