# How to build a SQLite Query to handle string containing an apostrophe

Tags: c#, sqlite, winrt-xaml

If the string `company` contains an apostrophe, this will cause an error.

Example: Company name like *"William's store"*.

How to build an SQLite Query that will handle this kind of problem using SQLite-Net api.

```
I am using SQLite-Net api and I tried both and they did not work.

In SQLite-Net api, I think there is no Parameters. What other alternative that I can use?


private async void GetCustomerVATGroup(string Company)
{


1) 

string strChkName = Company.Replace("'", "''"); // or Company.Replace("'","\'");

var allUsers = await db.QueryAsync<Customer>(

"Select * From Customer Where CompanyName ='" + strChkName + "'");


2) 

var allUsers = await db.QueryAsync<Customer>(

"Select * From Customer Where CompanyName =''" + Company + "''");


}
```

Comment: sqllite-net does have parameters: `QueryAsync<T> (string sql, params object[] args)` I added a code snippet on my answer for reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [SqlLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL. BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and
>   preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. ... A literal value can
>   also be the token "NULL".

So you can escape it with a string replace but the best way to query a db is to avoid string concatenation for avoiding [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The best practice is to use [Parameterized Querys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141599/parameterized-queries-in-sqlite)

In sqllite-net they are passed as argument with the method:

```
var allUsers = await db.QueryAsync<Customer>("Select * From Customer Where CompanyName ='?'", Company);
```

Comment: I m using SQLite-Net api. Try both and not sure if this is correct: string strCpy = "William's store"; string strNewCpy = strCpy.Replace("'" ,"\'") ?

Comment: @MilkBottle you have to escape as sql wants and  not as the c# way: `strCpy.Replace("'","''")`

Comment: I am not familiar with this parameter. What If I have more parameters in the Select-statement? How to get the result out? I will try it soon. Appreciate if you have any example of this type.

Comment: @MilkBottle You can use `?1` `?2` and pass a list of parameters