# Why am I getting "Invalid Cast Exception" with this SQLite code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, casting, windows-ce, executescalar

I've got this code to get a count from a SQLite table:

```
internal static bool TableExistsAndIsNotEmpty(string tableName)
{
    int count;
    string qry = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
    {
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, con);
        count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return count > 0;
}
```

When it runs, I get, "*Invalid Cast Exception*"

As is probably obvious, the value being returned from the query is an int, that is to say the count of records (I get "2" when I run the query, namely "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WorkTables" in Sqlite Browser).

So what is being invalidly cast here?

As a sort of a side note, I know it's better to use query parameters, and I found out how to do this in a Windows Store App here [[How can I use SQLite query parameters in a WinRT app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685223/how-can-i-use-sqlite-query-parameters-in-a-winrt-app]), but don't know how to do it in an oldfangled (Windows Forms/Windows CE) app.

I would think it would be something like this:

```
string qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?";
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(HHSUtils.GetDBConnection()))
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);
    count = cmd.ExecuteScalar(qry, tableName);
}
```

...but nothing of the ilk that I tried compiled.

Comment: For the side note: You can't substitute parameters for table names, only for values. Your `String.Format` is perfectly fine here as long as `tableName` doesn't come from user input.

Comment: `So what is being invalidly cast here?` The exception you get may say the line.

Comment: @L.B: No, that's all it says.

Comment: An exception without stacktrace?

Comment: @L.B: It's a design-time exception; that's all it gives me. Maybe the related warning, which I just noticed, is telling: Warning 1 The element 'metadata' has invalid child element 'type'. List of possible elements expected: 'value'. C:\Handheld21\HHS\frmNewDelivery.resx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context the ExecuteScalar returns a `System.Int64`.
Applying the (int) cast creates the exception you are seeing

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType());  // System.Int64
```

You could solve your problem with Convert.ToInt32

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, con);
count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Tried with 1.0.92 version of SQLite and it returns an System.Int64. Try it yourself with the code above.

Comment: You've embarrassed me, I missed the SQLite. I'll rescind my vote and comment due to lack of knowledge of that platform.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram no problem I recognize your willingness to help.

Comment: I should add that the same code in Sql Server works without exceptions.

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly now. I'll try to keep that in mind for my Windows Store App project that uses SQLite, as I reckon the same applies in that brave new world.